# React Rerender Child Component When New Record Inserted

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have parent component "company" and child component "person". When i insert new company person record,i want to rerender only person component. But i unable to to do it. When i want to add new person to company and show new record after saving,I cant show new record on the list.

[image]

**Company View Component**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useCallback } from "react";
import { Link, useParams } from "react-router-dom";

import { useTranslation } from "react-i18next";
import { APIClient } from "../../helpers/AxiosHelper";

import CComments from "../../components/common/CComments";
import CBreadCrumb from "../../components/common/CBreadCrumb";
import CImage from "../../components/common/CImage";
import withRouter from "../../components/common/withRouter";
import CToast from "../../components/common/CToast";
import CCommunication from "../../components/common/CCommunication";
import {
  DropdownItem,
  DropdownMenu,
  DropdownToggle,
  UncontrolledDropdown,
} from "reactstrap";
import CModal from "../../components/common/CModal";
import useModal from "../../components/hooks/useModal";
import PersonForm from "../persons/PersonEdit/PersonForm";

const CompanyView = (props) => {
  const { t } = useTranslation();
  const { isModalOpen, showHideModal } = useModal();
  const { refresh, onRefreshList } = useModal();
  const params = useParams();

  const api = new APIClient();

  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [company, setCompany] = useState();
  const [persons, setPersons] = useState([]);
  // const forceUpdate = React.useCallback(() => GetPersonsByCompanyId(params.id), []);
  // const handleMenu = useCallback((id) => GetPersonsByCompanyId(id), []);

  useEffect(() => {
      onShowData(params.id);
      GetPersonsByCompanyId(params.id);

  }, []);

  const NewPersonNavigator = async () => {
    showHideModal();
  }

  const GetPersonsByCompanyId = useCallback((id) => {
    if (id === null || id === undefined || id === "") return;

    setLoading(true);

    const form = {
      CompanyId: params.id
    }
    api
      .post("/Persons/List", form) //Persons/SelectList/TestCompaniesId2
      .then((response) => {
        if (response.Result) {
          setPersons(response.List);
        } else {
          //props.router.navigate("/404", { replace: true });
        }
      })
      .finally(() => {
        setLoading(false);
      });
  }, [persons]);

  async function onShowData(id) {
    if (id === null || id === undefined || id === "") return;

    setLoading(true);

    await api
      .get(`/Companies/Get/${id}`)
      .then((response) => {
        if (response.Result) {
          setCompany(response.Record);
        } else {
          props.router.navigate("/404", { replace: true });
        }
      })
      .finally(() => {
        setLoading(false);
      });
  };

  const onEditData = async () => {
    props.router.navigate(`/company-edit/${company?.Id}`);
  };

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <CToast />
      <div className="page-content">
        <div className="container-fluid">
          <CBreadCrumb
            title={t("Companies.View.Header")}
            parentTitle={t("Companies.List.Header")}
            parentUrl="/company-list"
            closable={true}
            returnURL="/company-list"
          />
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col-xl-9 col-lg-8">
              <div className="card">
                <div className="card-body">
                  <div className="text-muted">
                    <h5 className="mt-2 mb-3 fw-semibold text-uppercase">
                      {company?.Name}
                      <span className="ms-1">
                        {company?.Status === 1 ? (
                          <label className="badge bg-success-subtle text-success">{company?.StatusName}</label>
                        ) : (
                          <label className="badge bg-danger-subtle text-danger">{company?.StatusName}</label>
                        )}
                      </span>

                      <div className="float-end me-1">
                        <button
                          type="button"
                          className="btn btn-soft-success btn-sm rounded-circle"
                          onClick={onEditData}
                        >
                          <i className="ri-pencil-line"></i>
                        </button>
                      </div>
                    </h5>

                    <div className="table-responsive">
                      <table className="table mb-0">
                        <tbody>
                          <tr>
                            <th scope="row" style={{ width: "150px" }}>
                              {t("Companies.Label.TaxOffice")}
                            </th>
                            <th scope="row" style={{ width: "2px" }}>
                              :
                            </th>
                            <td>{company?.TaxOffice}</td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <th scope="row">{t("Companies.Label.TaxId")}</th>
                            <th scope="row">:</th>
                            <td>{company?.TaxId}</td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <th scope="row">{t("Companies.Label.TaxId")}</th>
                            <th scope="row">:</th>
                            <td>{company?.TaxId}</td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <th scope="row">{t("Companies.Label.SectorId")}</th>
                            <th scope="row">:</th>
                            <td>{company?.Sector?.Name}</td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <th scope="row">{t("Companies.Label.CompanyType")}</th>
                            <th scope="row">:</th>
                            <td>{company?.CompanyTypeName}</td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <th scope="row">{t("Companies.Label.CentralId")}</th>
                            <th scope="row">:</th>
                            <td>{company?.CentralRegistryId}</td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <th scope="row">{t("Companies.Label.TradeId")}</th>
                            <th scope="row">:</th>
                            <td>{company?.TradeRegistryId}</td>
                          </tr>
                        </tbody>
                      </table>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <CCommunication
                    id="comList"
                    label={t("Communications.Label.Header")}
                    lang={t}
                    relationId={company?.Id}
                    className="mt-3"
                  />
                </div>
              </div>

              <CComments title={t("Comments.Label.Header")} height="300px" lang={t} relationId={company?.Id} />
            </div>

            <div className="col-xl-3 col-lg-4">
              <div className="text-center">
                <div className="card">
                  <div className="card-body p-0">
                    <div className="profile-user position-relative d-inline-block mx-auto m-2">
                      <CImage
                        linkCode={company?.Id}
                        howMany={1}
                        linkType="CompanyLogo"
                        aspectRatio={1}
                        //stencilType="circle"
                        width={128}
                        lang={t}
                      />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="card">
                {/* CardHeader Başlangıç */}
                <div className="card-header align-items-center d-flex border-bottom-dashed">
                  <h4 className="card-title mb-0 flex-grow-1">Persons</h4>
                  <div className="flex-shrink-0">
                    <button
                      type="button"
                      onClick={NewPersonNavigator}
                      className="btn btn-success btn-sm"
                      data-bs-toggle="modal"
                      data-bs-target="#inviteMembersModal"
                    >
                      <i className="ri-add-line text-light me-2 align-bottom"><span className="text-light">{t("General.Button.New")}</span></i>
                    </button>
                  </div>
                </div>
                {/* CardHeader Son */}
                {/* CardBody Başlangıç */}
                <div className="card-body">
                  <div className="table-responsive table-card">
                    <table className="table table-borderless table-nowrap align-middle mb-0">
                      <tbody>
                        {persons?.map((item, key) => (
                          <tr key={key}>
                            <td className="d-flex">
                              <img src={window.REACT_APP_API_URL + "/Files/ShowImage?id=" + item.Id} alt="" className="avatar-xs rounded-3 me-2 material-shadow" />
                              <div>
                                <h5 className="fs-13 mb-0">{item.FullName}</h5>
                                <p className="fs-12 mb-0 text-muted">{item.TitleName}</p>
                              </div>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                              <UncontrolledDropdown>
                                <DropdownToggle
                                  type="button"
                                  className="btn btn-icon btn-sm fs-16 text-muted dropdown material-shadow-none"
                                  tag="button"
                                >
                                  <i className="ri-more-fill"></i>
                                </DropdownToggle>
                                <DropdownMenu>
                                  <li>
                                    <DropdownItem
                                      tag={Link}
                                      to={`/person-view/${item.Id}`}
                                      target="_blank"
                                    >
                                      <i className="ri-eye-fill text-muted me-2 align-bottom"></i><span className="">{t("General.Table.Button.View")}</span>
                                    </DropdownItem>
                                  </li>
                                  {/* <li>
                                    <DropdownItem>
                                      <i className="ri-star-fill text-muted me-2 align-bottom"></i>Favourite
                                    </DropdownItem>
                                  </li>
                                  <li>
                                    <DropdownItem>
                                      <i className="ri-delete-bin-5-fill text-muted me-2 align-bottom"></i>Delete
                                    </DropdownItem>
                                  </li> */}
                                </DropdownMenu>
                              </UncontrolledDropdown>
                            </td>
                          </tr>
                        ))}
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                  </div>
                </div>
                {/* CardBody Son */}
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <CModal
        title={t("General.Modal.Header.Update")}
        size="md"
        className=""
        isModalOpen={isModalOpen}
        toggle={showHideModal}
        onRefreshList={onRefreshList}
      >
        <PersonForm id={""} companyId={params.id}
          toggle={showHideModal} 
          onReload={() => { GetPersonsByCompanyId(params.id) }}
        />
      </CModal>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

export default withRouter(CompanyView);
```

**Person Edit/Save Component**

```
import React, { useMemo, useEffect, useState } from "react";

import { useTranslation } from "react-i18next";

import * as Yup from "yup";
import { useFormik } from "formik";

import { APIClient } from "../../../helpers/AxiosHelper";

import { EnumCommSubtype, EnumCompanyType, EnumGender, EnumStatus } from "../../../components/constants/CConst";
import CButton from "../../../components/common/CButton";
import CSelect from "../../../components/common/CSelect";
import CInput from "../../../components/common/CInput";
import CToast, { CShowToast } from "../../../components/common/CToast";
import CBreadCrumb from "../../../components/common/CBreadCrumb";
import CImage from "../../../components/common/CImage";
import withRouter from "../../../components/common/withRouter";
import CTextArea from "../../../components/common/CTextArea";

const PersonForm = (props) => {
  const { t } = useTranslation();

  const api = new APIClient();

  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  const formikForm = useFormik({
    initialValues: {
      hdnId: "",
      txtTitleName: "",
      txtName: "",
      txtSurname: "",
      txtDescription: "",
      ddlCompanyId: "",
      ddlGender: "",
      ddlStatus: "",
    },
    validationSchema: Yup.object({
      txtName: Yup.string().required(t("Validation.Rule.Required")),
      txtSurname: Yup.string().required(t("Validation.Rule.Required")),
      //ddlCompanyId: Yup.string().nullable().required(t("Validation.Rule.Required")),
      ddlGender: Yup.string().nullable().required(t("Validation.Rule.Required")),
      ddlStatus: Yup.string().nullable().required(t("Validation.Rule.Required")),
    }),
    validateOnChange: false,
    validateOnBlur: false,
    onSubmit: async (values) => {
      await onSaveData(values);
    },
  });

  const setFormikFields = (values) => {
    formikForm.setFieldValue("hdnId", values ? values.Id : "");
    formikForm.setFieldValue("txtTitleName", values ? values.TitleName : "");
    formikForm.setFieldValue("txtName", values ? values.Name : "");
    formikForm.setFieldValue("txtSurname", values ? values.Surname : "");
    formikForm.setFieldValue("txtDescription", values ? values.Description : "");
    formikForm.setFieldValue("ddlCompanyId", values ? values.CompanyId : "");
    formikForm.setFieldValue("ddlGender", values ? values.Gender : "");
    formikForm.setFieldValue("ddlStatus", values ? values.Status : "");
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    onShowData(props.id);
  }, []);

  const onShowData = async (id) => {
    formikForm.resetForm();

    if (id === null || id === undefined || id === "") return;

    formikForm.setFieldValue("hdnId", id);

    setLoading(true);

    await api
      .get(`/Persons/Get/${id}`)
      .then((response) => {
        if (response.Result) {
          setFormikFields(response.Record);
        } else {
          props.router.navigate("/404", { replace: true });
        }
      })
      .finally(() => {
        setLoading(false);
      });
  };

  const onSaveData = async (values) => {
    setLoading(true);

    var form = {
      Id: values.hdnId,
      TitleName: values.txtTitleName,
      Name: values.txtName,
      Surname: values.txtSurname,
      Description: values.txtDescription,
      CompanyId: props.companyId ? props.companyId : values.ddlCompanyId,
      Gender: values.ddlGender,
      Status: values.ddlStatus,
    };
    console.log("props.companyId", form)
    await api
      .post("/Persons/Save", form)
      .then((response) => {
        if (response.Result && response.Record && response.Record.Id != "") {
          formikForm.setFieldValue("hdnId", response.Record.Id);
          CShowToast("success", t("General.Info.Success.Save"));
          if (props.companyId) {
            
            props.toggle();
          }
          else {
            props.router.navigate(`/person-view/${response.Record.Id}`);
          }
        } else {
          CShowToast("error", response.Msg);
        }
      })
      .finally(() => {
        setLoading(false);
      });
  };

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <CToast />
      <div className="card">
        <div className="card-body">
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col-lg-12">
              <form onSubmit={formikForm.handleSubmit}>
                <div className="row">
                  <div className="col-lg-4 mb-2">
                    <CInput
                      id="txtName"
                      label={t("Persons.Label.Name")}
                      type="text"
                      className="form-control"
                      maxLength={250}
                      onChange={formikForm.handleChange}
                      value={formikForm.values.txtName || ""}
                      error={formikForm.errors.txtName}
                      required={true}
                    />
                  </div>
                  <div className="col-lg-4 mb-2">
                    <CInput
                      id="txtSurname"
                      label={t("Persons.Label.Surname")}
                      type="text"
                      className="form-control"
                      maxLength={250}
                      onChange={formikForm.handleChange}
                      value={formikForm.values.txtSurname || ""}
                      error={formikForm.errors.txtSurname}
                      required={true}
                    />
                  </div>
                  <div className="col-lg-4 mb-2">
                    <CInput
                      id="txtTitleName"
                      label={t("Persons.Label.TitleName")}
                      type="text"
                      className="form-control"
                      maxLength={250}
                      onChange={formikForm.handleChange}
                      value={formikForm.values.txtTitleName || ""}
                      error={formikForm.errors.txtTitleName}
                      required={false}
                    />
                  </div>
                  {props.companyId === undefined && <div className="col-md-4 mb-2">
                    <CSelect
                      id="ddlCompanyId"
                      label={t("Persons.Label.CompanyId")}
                      optionsUrl="/Companies/SelectList"
                      form={formikForm}
                      value={formikForm.values.ddlCompanyId}
                      error={formikForm.errors.ddlCompanyId}
                      required={true}
                      lang={t}
                    />
                  </div>}
                  <div className="col-lg-4 mb-2">
                    <CSelect
                      id="ddlGender"
                      label={t("Persons.Label.Gender")}
                      options={EnumGender}
                      form={formikForm}
                      value={formikForm.values.ddlGender}
                      error={formikForm.errors.ddlGender}
                      required={true}
                      lang={t}
                    />
                  </div>
                  <div className="col-lg-4 mb-2">
                    <CSelect
                      id="ddlStatus"
                      label={t("Persons.Label.Status")}
                      options={EnumStatus}
                      form={formikForm}
                      value={formikForm.values.ddlStatus}
                      error={formikForm.errors.ddlStatus}
                      required={true}
                      lang={t}
                    />
                  </div>
                  <div className="col-md-12 mb-2">
                    <CTextArea
                      id="txtDescription"
                      label={t("Persons.Label.Description")}
                      type="text"
                      className="form-control"
                      maxLength={500}
                      onChange={formikForm.handleChange}
                      value={formikForm.values.txtDescription || ""}
                      error={formikForm.errors.txtDescription}
                      rows={3}
                      required={false}
                    />
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div className="d-flex justify-content-end mt-4">
                  <button type="button" className="btn btn-light mx-2" onClick={() => props.router.navigate(-1)}>
                    {t("General.Button.Back")}
                  </button>
                  <CButton type="submit" className="btn btn-primary" isLoading={isLoading}>
                    {t("General.Button.Save")}
                  </CButton>
                </div>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

export default React.memo(withRouter(PersonForm));
```